# How to restart Vaadin session?

Tags: session, vaadin, restart

After logout I need to invalidate session and start a new immediately. I used the function

```
VaadinSession.getCurrent().getSession().invalidate();
```

After several seconds a red box "Session expired" appears. User must click on it or press F5. How to avoid it and to display new session page immediately?

In javascript is it easy:

```
document.location='/';
```

How to do the same in Vaadin? The behavior should be the same as by first visit the page after restarting explorer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my project I use this:

```
Page.getCurrent().setLocation( "/" );
VaadinSession.getCurrent().close();
```

Comment: It works: page.setLocation(VaadinServlet.getCurrent().getServletConfig().getServletContext().getContextPath())