# How to invalidate session in Vaadin 7 aplication?

Tags: session, jboss, vaadin7

I've got a Vaadin 7 application which authenticates against ldap with a security-domain configured in my server's standalone.xml (jboss eap6). Everything works fine until i try to log out.

In my Vaadin UI i've got a logout method:

```
public void logout(){
    VaadinService.getCurrentRequest().getWrappedSession().invalidate();
    this.close();
}
```

When i execute the method i get the message:

> SESSION EXPIRED Take note of any unsaved data, and click here or press ESC key to continue.

But once i do it refreshes the page and i'm still logged in

Is there anything else i need to do to properly close the session?

Thanks!

Comment: [How to restart Vaadin session?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26404821/how-to-restart-vaadin-session)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you can't close the application because you've just invalidated the session. Try closing the application before you invalidate the session. Something like this:

```
public void logout(){
    HttpSession ses = VaadinService.getCurrentRequest().getWrappedSession();
    this.close();
    ses.invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't with the way i was closing the session in Vaadin. The problem is that Jboss keeps the ldap user authenticated. So after i closed the session with

```
public void logout(){
    VaadinService.getCurrentRequest().getWrappedSession().invalidate();
    this.close();
}
```

i would somehow get a new session id but the server kept the user authenticated. I solved it using the same snippet to logout but managing the ldap login from within my application. Since i don't use the jboss security-domain and instead use my own login screen to go against ldap by code the problem is gone.